# How to select option in webpage using scrapy

Tags: python, reactjs, scrapy, pycharm

consider [this website](https://www.timeanddate.com/holidays/us/)

There is a select option for year on the website:

```
<select id="year" name="year">
<option value="2000">2000</option>
<option value="2001">2001</option>
<option value="2002">2002</option></select>
```

I want to select options from `2010-2020` and then scrape the info. How do I begin?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you select an year, the page redirects to `https://www.timeanddate.com/holidays/us/<year>`. So you're better off just using that url in your scraper.

```py
for year in range(2010, 2021, 1):
    url = f'https://www.timeanddate.com/holidays/us/{year}'
    yield scrapy.Request(url, callback=self.my_callback)
```